# Conditionally apply bootstrap css class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

i am learning bootstrap, need help. 
I have row, then i have a custom_class  which i just need to use when display not extra small (xs). How to do that?

```
<div class="col-md-7 custom_class">Left</div><div class="col-md-5">Right</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: If you `custom_class` has `@media queries` then it will take care of your screen width.

Comment: it's works, appreciated. thank you sir

Comment: Anytime.. happy coding.. :)